# Arithmetic expression nor properly parsed in yacc grammar

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I have the following `yacc`:

```
%{
#include  <stdio.h>
extern FILE* yyin;
extern char* yytext;

%}

%token VAR ID_NAME TYPE_STRING TYPE_BOOL TYPE_NUMBER
%token CONST VALUE_STRING VALUE_BOOL VALUE_NUMBER

%left '*' '/'
%left '+' '-'

%%

program
    : declarations
    ;

declarations
    : declaration
    | declarations declaration
    ;

declaration
    : var_declaration
    | const_declaration
    ;

value
    : VALUE_BOOL
    | VALUE_STRING
    ;

arithmetic_expression
    : arithmetic_expression '+' arithmetic_expression
    | arithmetic_expression '-' arithmetic_expression
    | arithmetic_expression '*' arithmetic_expression
    | arithmetic_expression '/' arithmetic_expression
    | '(' arithmetic_expression ')'
    | VALUE_NUMBER
    ;

initializer
    : value
    | arithmetic_expression
    ;

initialization
    : ID_NAME '=' initializer
    ;

init_list
    : initialization
    | init_list ',' initialization
    ;

init_or_id
    : initialization
    | ID_NAME
    ;

init_or_id_list
    : init_or_id
    | init_or_id_list ',' init_or_id
    ;

var_declaration
    : VAR ':' type init_or_id_list ';' { printf("%s booyah\n", $1);  } 
    ;

const_declaration: CONST ':' type init_list ';' {printf("koskos\n");}
    ;

type: TYPE_NUMBER 
    | TYPE_STRING
    | TYPE_BOOL
    ;

%%
void yyerror (char const *s) {
    fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{

    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

One of the features should be to allow the user to initialize variables and constants with (the value of) arithmetic expressions. Something like this `var:number = (1+2+3);`. However, I am not sure why, but the parser only recognizes expressions which make use of the operators `*` and `/`. Giving me a syntactic error when I use expressions which make use of the operators `+` and `-`.

This is the associated `lex` file:

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

%}

id_name [a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9])*
value_string \"([a-zA-Z0-9*+z=])*\"
value_number [+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+

%%

"var"                   { return VAR;  }
"const"                 { return CONST; }
"string"                { return TYPE_STRING; }
"number"                { return TYPE_NUMBER; }
"bool"                  { return TYPE_BOOL; }
"true"                  { return VALUE_BOOL; }
"false"                 { return VALUE_BOOL; }

{value_number}          { return VALUE_NUMBER; }
{value_string}          { return VALUE_STRING; }
{id_name}               { return ID_NAME; }


","                     { return ','; }
":"                     { return ':'; }
";"                     { return ';'; }
"="                     { return '='; }
"+"                     { return '+'; }
"-"                     { return '-'; }
"*"                     { return '*'; }
"/"                     { return '/'; }
"("                     { return '('; }
")"                     { return ')'; }


%%
```

I compile the file by using the following commands:

```
yacc -vd grammar.y
flex -l lex.l
gcc -Wall -o lang lex.yy.c y.tab.c -ll -lfl
```

For example, this expression: `var:number var1=12*12;` is successfully recognized. But this one: `var:number var1=12+12;` results in a `syntax error`. I am not sure what I din wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the flex `--debug` option. That will generate a scanner which shows you a trace of what it is doing. I think you will quickly see the problem.

#### Spoiler

> `+12` is lexed as a single number token, not an operator followed by a number

Comment: It turned out the regex for a number was the problem. I removed the `[+-]` part. Thanks.

Comment: @cristid9: Yep. But it's useful to know about the `--debug` option.